# Issue - How to reset pager back to page 1 in Angulas js pagination-control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I've been working with the pagination directive. By basic setup is a single page which allows the user to enter search criteria and then click search to see the results. The results are displayed on the same page, below the search input fields. The pagination is working great, but let's say the user goes to page 3 and then decides to do a new search. The user changes the search criteria, clicks search again but the pagination controller is never reset to 1...item 3 is still highlighted.

What is the proper way to reset the pagination control back to page 1?

`<dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>`

Comment: check ng-class is properly works. After second search still pagination 3, click pagination 1, anything happen? changes happening relate records?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.$watch`. Just watch the page number by `$scope.$watch` or when user change search criteria and click search just reset `pagenumber = 1` .